# .NET MAUI Button Text Concatenation

Tags: .net, maui

Does anyone know how to create a button in .NET MAUI where the text of the button contains multiple elements?

For example, I want to create a button where it has an icon and text, The icon is a binding to a static resource. Looking around, it looks like you can do it by using multi bindings by adding direct content to the button element in XAML, but .NET MAUI give an error stating that you cannot set direct content on a button.

I have tried adding direct content to the button, but that didn't work and other than that - I couldn't find much else to try.

Please help.

Comment: Use an ImageButton

Comment: The icon I want to use is not an image. It's from FontAwesome and is included in the project as a font so technically it uses the Text element to show the image.

E.g.

`<Button Text="{x:Static models:FaRegular.PenToSquare}" />`

Comment: That's useful information you should have included in your original question.  You could try a multi binding, or use a Label with multiple Spans and a GestureRecognizer

Comment: You can use a Label with Spans or you could also build your own type of Button control by using a Grid, several Labels and a GestureRecognizer. You have plenty of options, special cases are just not covered by the standard controls so you need to build something yourself.

Comment: Setting a TapGestureRecognizer for the border is better than using the button in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You best bet is to use either a VerticalStackLayout or a Grid including a label and the button.

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Button/>
    <Label/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

or an example with Grid inside a border

```
<Border>
    <Grid>
       <Button VerticalOptions="Start"/>
       <Label VerticalOptions="End"/>
    </Grid>

    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
             Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
             Command="..."
             CommandParameter="..."/>
            
    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
</Border>
```

Also note that if the user taps the label and not the icon then your code will not execute. You have to include also code to your label. The same applies if the user taps the border.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The native Button from MAUI (since .NET7 - tested on .NET8) has a ImageSource property which accepts a ImageSource and a FontImageSource. This means you can  easily add an icon next to the text.

Example:

```
<Button Text="Take Picture"
        ContentLayout="Right, 10"
        Command="{Binding TakePhotoCommand}"
        Margin="10"
        FontSize="Medium">
    <Button.ImageSource>
        <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xf30c;" 
                         FontFamily="FontAwesomeRegular"/>
    </Button.ImageSource>
</Button>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: "ContentLayout" determines the position and padding of the icon options are: left, right, top, and bottom followed by the spacing value